# Dynamic library tensorflow.dll failed when building with GPU enabled

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gpu

Has someone been able to build the static or dynamic library for tensorflow (GPU enabled) with cmake or bazel  in windows?

I have been trying to build the library with  GPU enabled and it raises different errors during the building. It would be great if someone could guide with the steps to follow in order to build the library.

The steps I have followed are in the link below:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

Thanks.

Comment: Well... what are the errors? You haven't provided nearly enough information.

Comment: Sorry for that. The errors I have are some of them: 1. atomicAdd is not defined. 2. fatal error C1060: insufficient heap space in compiler. I have asked about this error in the following link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13448. Thanks

Comment: You may want to try using CMake instead. It can be found in the repo in tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake. I have not had success building using Bazel, but CMake has always worked.